# How to build a Mac application?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I'm a Linux geek

After asking on mailing-list, search on internet, read a book about mac programming,...

My questions is simple:

1. How to compile a Mac application ?

Is a there a special commandline as with windows:

`cc -mwindows -lmingw32 ...`

2. How to deal with the *.dyn.lib for packaging ?

Thanks for giving clear answers to my question because I have try all and nothing to do for building an app...!!!!

Sorry for the tone of the post but I'm weak for this theme.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Are we supposed to assume you don' have a Mac? I mean are you trying to develop, or to cross-develop?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard. There is some work done by the [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/en/) team [here](https://devs.openttd.org/~truebrain/compile-farm/apple-darwin9.txt) but it might be too outdated.

You could try using [osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) which is a cross compilation toolchain ready for work but you probably won't be able to link to native frameworks.

Generally speaking, it might be a lot easier to just use Travis to compile for Mac if you're a heavy Linux user and don't have access to Macs.